# Is there an easier way to extract combined fitted values and forecast values of an ARIMA in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

Simple question -- I want to extract the fitted values and mean forecast of an ARIMA as one single time series, using R.  Right now, I use this slow and cumbersome code:

```
x<-auto.arima(y)
z<-forecast(x, 365)

fitted<-z$fitted
mean<-z$mean
merged<-merge.zoo(fitted, mean)
merged$fitted[is.na(merged$fitted)]<-0
merged$mean[is.na(merged$mean)]<-0

finalforecast<-merged$fitted+ merged$mean
```

There must be an esier way to do this, but looking at the documentation, I'm drawing a blank.  I really want to avoid the hassle of merging the time series, then dropping in zeroes (to fill the NAs), and then doing the addition.  I know I can create my own function, but I'd be surprised if there isn't something simple that's pre-baked.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not surprised there's nothing pre-baked. Why on earth would you want to do that? The fitted values are one-step in-sample forecasts, and you are joining them with out-of-sample multi-step forecasts.

Comment: I'm combining the two for data storage uses, mostly.  But, as my colleague who concentrates on cross-sectional work pointed out, having one set of fitted values combined with forecast can be useful when you're decomposing a data series, to see how much of the data can be explained by your model (and how much you expect to explain going out).  Given that, what do you suggest as a better way to do this?  Perhaps a back-test of the foretasted values of the ARIMA over time? Appreciate your time -- and your book.

Comment: You could use MASE values, in-sample and out-of-sample. See http://otexts.com/fpp/2/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `c(z$fitted, z$mean)`?

EDIT:
If you need a `ts` object: `ts(c(z$fitted, z$mean), start=start(y), frequency=frequency(y))`

Comment: Thanks -- that makes perfect sense.  Still, a bit of work to get this data out....